# Header is coming underneath the lightbox

Tags: html, wordpress, css

header is coming underneath the lightbox when scroll any way to get that header above the light box [image] http://csdm4.com/design-build/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caught the error, the below code fixes:

```css
div.pp_overlay {position: absolute !important;}
```

[image]

Comment: I am using firefox and resolution 1920x1080

Comment: You need to have `position: relative` or `absolute` in order for z-index` to work.

Comment: @BrianBennett It has already `position: fixed`. It works for `fixed` too!

Comment: @PraveenKumar this issue comes up when i do scroll